# Docker container uses almost 20% of CPU after set entrypoint with while command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Build image using following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

...

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c","while true; do cat; done"]
```

Then execute "docker run" to start a container in detach mode, the CPU usage is 21.9%. But if i remove the ENTRYPOINT and run the while command inside a container, the CPU usage is very low.

Does anyone know why is this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't open stdin when you ran the container `cat` returns immediately and you're left with a spinning loop that eats up CPU cycles. If you run with `-i`, `-t`, or both, then `cat` will wait for input as expected.

```
docker run -itd image_name
```